# pandas can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have df like this:

```
df['Time']
2017-08-06 11:00:00+00:00
2017-08-08 15:00:00+00:00
2017-08-10 04:00:00+00:00
2017-08-12 23:00:00+00:00
2017-08-08 15:00:00+00:00
```

I want to slice it with condition

```
mask1=df['Time'] > datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-08-12', "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I get an error like

> can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Somehow I have to convert `df['Time']` to offset-naive.
Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 19):

It seems you need:

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.tz_localize(None)
```

Or:

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.tz_convert(None)
```

Or:

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

See also [`tz aware dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#tz-aware-dtypes).

Comment: I had tried 3rd option . It converted date-time in 2017-08-12T23:00:00.000000000 format.  Then I tried in top two options but output df  remains in same format. How to convert in simple  format 2017-08-12 23:00:00. I am printing o/p to csv file. When i print on o/p terminal , format is as exacted.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems using oldier version of pandas. So maybe help `df['Time'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Time'].astype('datetime64[ns]'))`

Comment: Tried with this option too. it's same o/p. I am using >>> pd.__version__
'0.16.2'

Comment: Then it is bug. Last version is `0.20.3` - there is no error.

Comment: yes . all three options do not work in expected format. Will check with version you mentioned. thanks

Comment: I am using the most recent version of Pandas, where the third option works perfectly fine.