# convert timestamptz to timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe df is the resulting from postgres tables. I want to apply a lambda function if the row respect the conditions below, in order to drop the zone if the date_ is timestamptz and cast with timestamp.

```
table1:
date_ = up_1
2013-09-27 14:19:46.825000+02:00
2017-03-28 10:10:10.305000+01:00
2019-05-10 10:10:10
table2:
date_ = up_2
2013-09-27 14:19:46.825000+02:00
None
2019-05-10 09:10:00
**expected output**
table 1: 
  2013-09-27 14:19:46
  2017-03-28 10:10:10
  2019-05-10 10:10:10
table 2: 
  2013-09-27 14:19:46
  None
  2019-05-10 09:10:00
```

im gotting error E TypeError: 'tzinfo' is an invalid keyword argument for this function. Thank you.
How can i correct my code below please?
My proposition:

```
if self.date_ in df.columns and df[str(self.date_)].dtypes== 'object' \
and df[str(self.date_)][df[str(self.date_)] != "None"]:
     df[str(self.date_)] = df[str(self.date_)].apply(lambda x: x if pd.isnull(x) else 
     x.replace(tzinfo=None))
```

Answer (score 0):

If need convert values to UTC add `utc=True` in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], utc=True)
```

If eed remove values after `+` use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `str[0]`:

```
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.split('+').str[0])
print (df)
                               date                            date1  \
0  2013-09-27 14:19:46.825000+02:00 2013-09-27 12:19:46.825000+00:00   
1  2017-03-28 10:10:10.305000+01:00 2017-03-28 09:10:10.305000+00:00   
2               2019-05-10 10:10:10        2019-05-10 10:10:10+00:00   

                    date2  
0 2013-09-27 14:19:46.825  
1 2017-03-28 10:10:10.305  
2 2019-05-10 10:10:10.000 

print (df.dtypes)
date                  object
date1    datetime64[ns, UTC]
date2         datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

EDIT:

If need remove values after `.`:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].astype(str).str.split('.').str[0]
#with convert to datetimes
#df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str).str.split('.').str[0])
print (df)

                  date
0  2013-09-27 14:19:46
1  2017-03-28 10:10:10
2  2019-05-10 10:10:10
```

EDIT1:

In your solution change:

```
 else x.replace(tzinfo=None)
```

to:

```
 else str(x).split('.')[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunatelly, i can't create new column beacause im working with big data. It's not really my expected output. I will update my original post to explain more. thank you

Comment: @biwia - So need solution from `EDIT` ?

Comment: yes, if you can help, i just added the expected output. thank you

Comment: @biwia - I think yes, added `EDIT` and `EDIT1` for new solutiones.

Comment: thank you, but now got this errror E   **TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes**

Comment: @biwia - What solution was used?

Comment: i used your edit1. I think because this row **else str(x).split('.')[0]** it doesn't drop the zone from timestamptz. THank you in advance.

Comment: Can you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46295446/2901002) ?

Comment: now i got this error. **ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()** :/

Comment: @biwia - It is weird, how possible `this error` from `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str).str.split('.').str[0])` ? Or you change solution some way?

Comment: yes from df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str).str.split('.').str[0])

Comment: i tried also the x.replace(tzinfo=None) it works fine, the problem is when i have none values, i don't know how to deal with.

Comment: @biwia - So missing values are strings? need change `if pd.isnull(x)` to `if x == 'None'` ?

Comment: same error. @jezrael :/ the error is in this row if self.date_ in df.columns and df[str(self.date_)].dtypes== 'object' \
and df[str(self.date_)][df[str(self.date_)] != "None"]:

Comment: @biwia - I see, it is wrong code. What is expected from this code?

Comment: @biwia How working if remove part `and df[str(self.date_)].dtypes== 'object' \
and df[str(self.date_)][df[str(self.date_)] != "None"]` ?

Comment: tables with none values cause this error E   TypeError: 'tzinfo' is an invalid keyword argument for this function. the other pass with success. .apply(lambda x: x if x == 'None' else x.replace(tzinfo=None))

Comment: @biwia so working well `.apply(lambda x: x if x == 'None' else x.replace(tzinfo=None))`?

Comment: the problem is if the table have none values. :/ @jezrael

Comment: should x in my case iterate over rows in the column **date_** .? right?